# Move class to a new/other package in intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I installed intelliJ and created a package of name "com.company" and created some classes and interfaces in that package. Now I created a new package "myCalculator" and created some classes as well. But now I see my new package is not having the main class, so I need to import the package manually. How do i bring my main class to my new package in IntelliJ. Thank You.

Comment: Select class and click `F6` button and move the class to a new package.

Answer (score 0):

You can just drag your files from package to package. Behind the scenes Java packages are just folders, so its is just the same as moving files between folders.

Answer (score 0):

Use refactor option.

1. Select a class of a package
2. right click on it and select refactor
3. choose move option and enter the desired destination package name